# Starting 6 HP outboard with cordless drill/driver

Tags: starting

I have a Honda BF6 outboard that only gets started each summer. Before winterizing, I drain the fuel etc., but it is still very difficult to start the 1st time in the summer.

I can remove the cover and pull starter and there is a 17 mm nut on the shaft. I can use a power drill to start it with this and it works well (I know it is slightly dangerous if I cannot disconnect the drill in time).

I would like to get a handheld battery drill/driver instead, but the one I have doesn't have enough torque. The ones with high torque are all impact drivers. My Q is -- would the hammer action damage my motor (or the nut) ? The impact drivers have a typical torque of over 1000 lb-in, but the usual drills are less than 200 lb-in. What is a good brand to look for ?
2nd question -- is there any type of one-way clutch available that fits these that would not allow the outboard to spin the drill ?

Comment: I know you know that this is a bad idea, but ask yourself (rhetorically) if it is really worth the risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, **yes** an impact version *would* be bad on your motor. You would basically be hammering away on the 17mm nut, torquing it beyond where it would need to be. This alone could cause the nut to break or the shaft upon which it tightens to become stripped or broken.

My suggestion to you if you want to continue to use the power device to get your motor started is two-fold:

1. Continue to use the corded power drill. The difference is, get the motor started while you are at home.
2. When the motor does begin to start, quit cranking it with the power drill and start to use the cord pull. This will alleviate any issues with over running the drill.

Answer (score 3):

Impact drivers don't produce a continuous high torque, they produce a repeated pulse of high torque.  This will not turn your engine over, it will just tighten the nut well.  It probably wont do the crank bearings any good either.

You want something with a [sprag clutch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprag_clutch) to allow one-way drive.

Comment: ...and make sure you're cranking it in the correct direction.  I know it sounds obvious but I've seen engines turned over backwards before (usually followed by much cursing and confusion).

Comment: Is there any sprag clutch available that will fit in a drill chuck and drive a 17 mm socket ? The ones I can find online tend to look like bearings and I'm not sure of how they would be attached.